# Override HTTP 500 Internal Server Error in Apache

Tags: apache, error-handling, vhosts, application-error

I am following the article [Custom error pages in Apache for JBoss AS7](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1334#comment-1748) to configure apache to override HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. I am facing below problem, any guess what's the issue?

In #2 in the above linked article

# (4) Setting error code 404 for "MyApp" application
    JkMount /MyApp/* nodeA;use_server_errors=404

In windows env it works where it points to jboss directly
    JkMount /MyApp/* jboss7;use_server_errors=500

But in linux where it points to load balancer
    JkMount /MyApp/* loadbalancer2;use_server_errors=500

This gives me error:
    jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2372): Could not find a worker for worker name=loadbalancer2;use_server_errors=500

Windows apache version is 2.2.17, linux apache version is 2.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem, it is due to the older version of mod_jk. The flag 'use_server_errors' was introduced in mod_jk 1.2.27. In my case linux Apache 2.5.1 has mod_jk 1.2.26 that's why it reads 'loadbalancer2;use_server_errors=500' as a whole. It works in windows because there Apache 2.2.17 has mod_jk 1.2.28 which knows to separate the flag from worker name.